# Timestamp with desired timezone format in SQL

Tags: sql, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to handle oracle database table columns with type 'Timestamp with Timezone'.
On fetching the format I need to get like --  2018-12-04T01:38:33.342373-08:00.

When I am trying to fetch from the table with following query, its getting returned like -- 2014-12-0922:10:40.776955IST

```
select to_char(a.creation_date,'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF6TZD')
  from TableName a;
```

I checked with multiple TZ format types but its not getting returned in the desired format(2019-01-01T01:38:33.342373-08:00) for me.

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query serving my purpose.

```
 select (to_char(a.creation_date,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF'))||DBTIMEZONE
  from TableName a;
```